# How to save a variable to Android using Cocos2D-JS?

Tags: javascript, android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I am trying to save a high score integer to the user's Android system, so that it can persist throughout all game-play experience.

I have read that using Cocos2D-X one can use `NSUserDefaults` but this doesn't seem to be available in the Cocos2D-JS API at all.

Anyone has any experience with this, is there any other efficient way how to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using Cocos2D-JS for compiling native apps, you can simply use `localStorage` just like if you were running your game in the browser :D

For example:

```
//Handle for quick access to Cocos2D's implementation of Local Storage:
var ls = cc.sys.localStorage;

var value = "foo";
var key  = "bar";

//This should save value "foo" on key "bar" on Local Storage
ls.setItem(key, value);

//This should read the content associated with key "bar" from Local Storage:
var data = ls.getItem(key);

cc.log(data); //Should output "foo" to the console.

//This should remove the contents of key "bar" from Local Storage:
ls.removeItem(key);

//This should print "null"
data = ls.getItem(key);
cc.log(data);
```

Comment: Do you know if the localStorage data is persistent when updating the game to a new version on Android?

Comment: I don't really know, I would guess so, but you should try and see for yourself what happens.