# Cocos2d-js file storage in cross-platform

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I am having a little problem with keeping some information.
We have a game where we use a hashmap to store all possible tasks for the player. The player can add more data to this and we want to save it locally. 
Is there any way to do this AND make it work as a native Windows app? 
We tried local storage, but this doesn't seem to work when ran on Windows.

Any ideas?

Comment: Local storage should work on any platform when used via cocos' API, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242672/how-to-save-a-variable-to-android-using-cocos2d-js

Comment: In theory, yes, it should. However, we tested it and it didn't. The game crashes as soon as we try to write something into the local storage.

Comment: You mean `cc.sys.localStorage.setItem(key, value);` throws an exeption? What kind of?